# PDf.js canvas scroll bar missing

Tags: pdf.js

I am using PDF.js to display PDF documents in my JSF page. My input is a blob which I pass to pdf.js . It works fine for documents with single pages but if a document has more than 1 page I see only the first page and I am unable to scroll. I tried encapsulating it with a `<div>` with overflow:scroll; property but I cannot navigate to the next page.

```
<div id="the-container" style="width:1000px;height:600px;overflow-y:scroll;">
  <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

A sample link for what I have used is below. Please help !

```
https://jsfiddle.net/qj9tau8e/
```

The sample document has 2 pages but only 1 is displayed

Comment: You have a missing quote in your source, or is that just in the example here?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo here.